# How do I use forkJoin with higher-order Observables in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I've followed this guide on how to cancel HTTP requests with the switchMap Operator [Guide](https://www.angularaddicts.com/p/unlock-the-power-of-http-request-cancellation)

I have following Component in my Angular project

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable, forkJoin, skip, switchMap } from 'rxjs';
import { Todo } from 'src/app/model/todo.model';
import { User } from 'src/app/model/user.model';
import { TodoService } from 'src/app/service/todo.service';
import { UserService } from 'src/app/service/user.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-todo',
  templateUrl: './todo.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./todo.component.scss']
})
export class TodoComponent implements OnInit{

  todos: Todo[] = [];
  users: User[] = [];

  fetchTodos$ = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<Todo[]>>(null);
  fetchUsers$ = new BehaviorSubject<Observable<User[]>>(null);

  public constructor(
    private todoService: TodoService,
    private userService: UserService
  ){}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchTodos$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(innerObservable => innerObservable)
    )
    .subscribe(todos => {
      this.todos = todos;
    });

    this.fetchUsers$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(innerObservable => innerObservable)
    )
    .subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
    });

    this.loadData();
  }

  loadData(){
    const getAllTodosObservable = this.todoService.getAllTodos();
    this.fetchTodos$.next(getAllTodosObservable);

    const getAllUsersObservable = this.userService.getAllUsers();
    this.fetchUsers$.next(getAllUsersObservable);

    forkJoin([this.fetchTodos$, this.fetchUsers$])
    .subscribe(_ => {
      this.processTodos();
    });
  }

  //Only process todos when all todos and users have been loaded
  processTodos(){
    console.log("Processing todos...")
  }
}
```

The problem is that forkJoin subscribe will never be called because the BehaviourSubjects are not completed.

```
forkJoin([this.fetchTodos$, this.fetchUsers$])
    .subscribe(_ => {
      this.processTodos();
  });
```

How would I achieve calling processTodos() when both requests are done without losing the functionality of HTTP cancellation?

I tried calling complete() on the BehaviourSubjects when requests were done like so

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchTodos$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(innerObservable => innerObservable)
    )
    .subscribe(todos => {
      this.todos = todos;
      this.fetchTodos$.complete();
    });

    this.fetchUsers$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(innerObservable => innerObservable)
    )
    .subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
      this.fetchUsers$.complete();
    });

    this.loadData();
  }
```

This will actually call the subscribe method of the forkJoin, but only once and not more.

I've also tried using combineLatest instead of forkJoin like this

```
loadData(){
    const getAllTodosObservable = this.todoService.getAllTodos();
    this.fetchTodos$.next(getAllTodosObservable);

    const getAllUsersObservable = this.userService.getAllUsers();
    this.fetchUsers$.next(getAllUsersObservable);

    combineLatest([this.fetchTodos$, this.fetchUsers$])
    .subscribe(_ => {
      this.processTodos();
    });
  }
```

The problem with that is, processTodos() will be called twice due to two values being emitted.

Last thing I tried was to use forkJoin() with the HTTP observables directly instead of the behaviour subjects like following

```
loadData(){
    const getAllTodosObservable = this.todoService.getAllTodos();
    this.fetchTodos$.next(getAllTodosObservable);

    const getAllUsersObservable = this.userService.getAllUsers();
    this.fetchUsers$.next(getAllUsersObservable);

    forkJoin([getAllTodosObservable, getAllUsersObservable])
    .subscribe(_ => {
      this.processTodos();
    });
  }
```

Here I have to problem that the HTTP requests are being sent twice because of two subscriptions.
Subscriptions in ngOnInit:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.fetchTodos$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(innerObservable => innerObservable)
    )
    .subscribe(todos => {
      this.todos = todos;
      this.fetchTodos$.complete();
    });

    this.fetchUsers$.pipe(
      skip(1),
      switchMap(innerObservable => innerObservable)
    )
    .subscribe(users => {
      this.users = users;
      this.fetchUsers$.complete();
    });

    this.loadData();
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you tried all combinations except for one.

It should work if you use `combineLatest` with the direct data streams (instead of the BehaviorSubjects).

Something like this:

```
  // Get all posts
  // Get all users
  postData$ = this.http.get<Post[]>(this.postUrl);
  userData$ = this.http.get<User[]>(this.userUrl);

  // Combine them.
  // Each of these will only emit once
  // The combineLatest won't emit until both streams have emitted.
  sub = combineLatest([
    this.postData$,
    this.userData$
  ]).subscribe(
    ([posts, users]) => this.processTodos(posts, users)
  )

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  processTodos(posts: Post[], users: User[]) {
    // whatever code here
    console.log("processing");
  }
```

I have an example here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-posts-user-combinelatest-deborahk

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, I've tried this approach and it does fire the subscribe method but I lose the functionality of HTTP request cancellation. If I load the data several times in a short time period, all requests are being processed, I only need the most recent requests to be processed and previous ones to be cancelled. I have my example on here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mrwcgf?file=src%2Fapp%2Fcomponent%2Ftodo%2Ftodo.component.ts

Comment: In general, you could try piping something like `.pipe(takeUntil(this.cancel$))` to the stream you want to interrupt, where `cancel$ = new Subject<void>()` and in the template `<button (click)="cancel$.next()">`.  However you'd want to hide it in an inner observable (to prevent `combineLatest` from dying), or to pipe it to each of the two requests. It can be tricky to maintain reliable UI data display after cancellation - data get get out of sync. Definitely too complex to fit into an SO comment :)

Comment: I provided a new answer that uses switchMap.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the two different `BehaviorSubject`, You could just use one `Subject`, and use `switchMap` on its emits like below

```
fetchTodosAndUsers$ = new Subject<void>();

ngOnInit(): void {
  this.fetchTodosAndUsers$.pipe(
    startWith(() => {}),
    switchMap(() => forkJoin([
      this.todoService.getAllTodos(),
      this.userService.getAllUsers()
    ])),
    map(([todos, users]) => {
      this.todos = todos;
      this.users = users;
      this.processTodos();
    })
   ).subscribe(); 
 }

loadData() {
  this.fetchTodosAndUsers$.next();
}

//Only process todos when all todos and users have been loaded
processTodos() {
  console.log('Processing todos...');
}
```

If you want to separate the two different calls

```
ngOnInit(): void {
  this.fetchTodo$.pipe(
    startWith(() => {}),
    switchMap(() => this.todoService.getAllTodos()),
    map((todos) => {
      this.todos = todos;
      this.processTodos();
    })
  ).subscribe();

  this.fetchUsers$.pipe(
    startWith(() => {}),
    switchMap(() => this.userService.getAllUsers()),
    map((users => {
      this.users = users;
      this.processUsersOrWhatEver();
    })
  ).subscribe();
}

loadData() {
  this.fetchTodo$.next();
  this.fetchUsers$.next();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how would this work if I want them to be decoupled. Right now I'm always stuck with fetching Todos and Users at one time. In future I might only want to call `processTodos()` if only the `getAllTodos()` request has been completed. My question is, how can I build this dynamically? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @Unrated, The logic you described says that you want to call both services on component `ngOnInit()`. So they are coupled in that sense. Thought you can use two subjects and call `next()` method on both of them in `loadData()` method, as my updated answer

Answer (score 0):

I left the original answer because it is useful as an answer to the original defined question.

Adding the requirement of using `switchMap`, the revised code is as follows:

```
export class TodoService {
  toDoUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos`;
  UserUrl = `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/users`;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  doLoading = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(true);
  doLoading$ = this.doLoading.asObservable();

  allData$ = this.doLoading$.pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.httpClient.get<Todo[]>(this.toDoUrl).pipe(
      combineLatestWith(this.httpClient.get<User[]>(this.UserUrl))
    )),
    map(([todos, users]) => this.processTodos(todos, users))
  )

  processTodos(todos: Todo[], users: User[]) {
    // whatever code here
    console.log("processing");
    return { todos, users };
  }

  loadData() {
    this.doLoading.next(true);
  }

}
```

Here the code sets up one single `BehaviorSubject` to define when to do the loading. It then uses a `switchMap` to make the http get cancellable.

The component code then looks like this:

```
export class TodoComponent {
  todos: Todo[] = [];
  users: User[] = [];

  sub = this.todoService.allData$.subscribe(
    alldata => {
      this.todos = alldata.todos;
      this.users = alldata.users;
    });

  public constructor(
    private todoService: TodoService,
    private userService: UserService
  ) {}

  loadData() {
    this.todoService.loadData();
  }
}
```

The resulting Stackblitz is here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-tnte6q